# VirtualBox - Two monitors - XRandR

Tags: screen, virtualbox, monitor, xrandr

[image: Error of XRandR]

Thats the problem.

I have two monitors...
Both are configurated on VirtualBox...
The VirtualBox Guest Addons are installed...

I dont know whats the problem is. I hope you can help me :)

The default configuration at the moment is, that the monitors are mirrored.
I mean, all what i do on the VBOX0 Screen, i do on the VBOX1 screen.
I cant use different windows on each monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, i got not enough space for the monitors...

[image: Bugfix]